# How to show custom post type column before date column

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to output columns pertaining to a CPT:

```
//set up new column to show custom meta theme_color
function pr_testimonials_column($column) {
    $column['testimonial_person_tagline'] = 'Person Tagline';

    return $column;
}

add_filter('manage_testimonials_posts_columns', 'pr_testimonials_column');

//show custom column data
function pr_show_testimonials_column($name) {
    global $post;
    switch ($name) {
        case 'testimonial_person_tagline':
            $testimonial_person_tagline = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_testimonial_person_tagline', true);
            echo $testimonial_person_tagline;
    }
}

add_action('manage_testimonials_posts_custom_column',  'pr_show_testimonials_column');
```

The result is this, with the date first and the columns second. How can I modify my code to show all of my custom columns first, and date column last?
[image]

Comment: Look this [Wordpress Stack Exchange post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8427/change-order-of-custom-columns-for-edit-panels)

Answer (score 4):

Find the key for the Date column, next step to unset it and then set after adding your custom column,

```
function pr_testimonials_column($column) {

    // Remove Date
    unset($column['date']);

    $column['testimonial_person_tagline'] = 'Person Tagline';
    $column['date'] = 'Date';

    return $column;
}
add_filter('manage_testimonials_posts_columns', 'pr_testimonials_column');
```

Hope this one helps.